# Find $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A^k x$

Tags: limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\displaystyle A=\left(\begin{matrix}.5&1\\0&.75\end{matrix}\right),x=\left(\begin{matrix}-2\\1\end{matrix}\right)$.

- Find $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A^k x$
- Find $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 {\Vert A^k x\Vert}A^k x$

I found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to be $\displaystyle \lambda_1=.5, v_1=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right),\lambda_2=.75,v_2=\left(\begin{matrix}4\\1\end{matrix}\right)$.

x can be expressed as $x=-6v_1+v_2$, then $\displaystyle Ax=-6(.5)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)+.75\left(\begin{matrix}4\\1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-6(.5)+.75(4)\\.75\end{matrix}\right)$

Then $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A^k x=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\begin{matrix}-6(.5)^k+(.75)^k(4)\\(.75)^k\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ ?

And what is $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 {\Vert A^k x\Vert}A^k x=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{-6(.5)^k+(.75)^k(4)}{\sqrt{(-6(.5)^k+(.75)^k(4))^2+((.75)^k)^2}}\\\frac{(.75)^k}{\sqrt{(-6(.5)^k+(.75)^k(4))^2+((.75)^k)^2}}\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\infty\\\infty\end{matrix}\right)$?

Comment: Both eigenvalues are (strictly) less than $1$ so $A^k$ goes to the zero matrix for larger $k$. That should answer the first part

Comment: As mentioned before, $\displaystyle lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A^k x$ is correct, but the other part is not correct. Roughly speaking, the $0.75^k$ term dominates so you would have $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0.25 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already did the first part, I will rewrite the second part in terms of the eigenvector decomposition

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\cdot(-6v_1)+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k\cdot(v_2)}{\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\cdot(-6v_1)+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k\cdot(v_2)\right|} \equiv \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{av+bw}{|av+bw|}$$

The two vectors are not orthogonal, and the magnitude of the sum of non orthogonal vectors is given by

$$|av+bw| = \sqrt{(av+bw)\cdot(av+bw)} = \sqrt{a^2|v|^2+2abv\cdot w + b^2|w|^2}$$

Plugging in the vectors we have, this simplifies to

$$\sqrt{a^2+8ab+17b^2} = |b|\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2+ 8\frac{a}{b}+17}$$

Now why did we pull out $b$ instead of $a$ when the same formula could have applied either way? It's because $\frac{a}{b}\to 0$, thus we can take the limit without a L'Hopital situatuon occurring. Meaning the limit simplifies to

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\frac{a}{b}v +  w}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2+ 8\frac{a}{b}+17}} \to \frac{w}{\sqrt{17}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

because $b>0$. In general you can see that the second limit will approach the unit eigenvector with the largest (by absolute value) eigenvalue.

Comment: excellent! I think the $-6$ in front of $-6v_1$ is neglected, but the answer turns out the same

Comment: @Stacker it is not, it is included in the $a$. That's why I had to phrase it as the limit goes to zero as opposed to $|b|>|a|$ because it's not true for small $k$

Comment: Ok thanks! The last sentence in your answer is great and gets to the point of this